# Firebase realtime database warning via react native expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I have just manually key in all the data in my firebase realtime database. But when i run my application (using react native expo), i get the following warning in my terminal:

```
[2023-02-06T09:53:41.782Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://******-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app (https://*******-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/)
```

What does this means? Does it means my firebase realtime database wont work at all?
Also I did a checked on my firebase realtime database URL, the url is the same as the one they ask me to change to before the URL in the bracket. What does this means? I am confused by this.

[image]

If I have to change the URL to the bracket one, how do i do it?

My current firebase config: I copied this from the firebase when I first started developing this app

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update following your comment and question update:** It appears that your Firebase config object doesn't contain the URL of your Realtime Database instance.

---

You didn't share your [Firebase config object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object) but it seems that it contains the URL of Realtime Database instance based in the default region, i.e. the `us-central1` region.

So you need to update your Firebase config object with the correct URL, corresponding to the `asia-southeast1` region.

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "API_KEY",
   authDomain: "PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
   // The value of `databaseURL` depends on the location of the database
   databaseURL: "https://******-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
   projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
   // ...
};
```

Comment: Sorry about it as I am still quite new to firebase. I had just uploaded the firebase config. Am I right to say that I just have to add the ```databaseURL: "https://******-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",``` in my firebase config?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, the app is able to run without warning for the database now!